# VIM: Deleting from current position until a space

Tags: vim

Often when developing I am confronted with a nested object that I'd like to delete from code in the middle of a line like this:

```
htmlDoc.WriteLine("<b><h3>" + this.cbAllSyncs.SelectedItem.ToString() + "</h3></b>");
```

The part that I'd like to delete is:

```
this.cbAllSyncs.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

I know I can count the number of words and periods and enter <kbd>7</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to delete from my current cursor position of "this".  However, what I'd love to do is not have to count at all and delete to the space with one command.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 409, accepted):

Try <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>. In general <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> deletes from current position till just before `x`. Just <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> moves the cursor to just before character `x` in current line.

To delete up to and including the space, use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>.

Comment: This works great!  It also gives me some added flexibility to get to other certain points within that object.  Thanks!

Comment: `df<space>` deletes upto and including the next space.

Comment: equally useful, dfT<space> deletes downto the previous space.

Comment: You can also add a count just before the `t` to delete up to that many characters. e.g. `d2t<space>` will delete up to two spaces.

Comment: I always use the mnemonic `t` as *'till*
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409134/english-mnemonics-to-vims-shortcuts

Comment: Is it possible to delete space to the first character with this method? Like delete until anything BUT space.

Answer (score 88):

You can use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> as [@glenn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607904/vim-deleting-from-current-position-until-a-space/#comment-1474811) suggested if you don't want to delete the space itself.

A [WORD](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/motion.html#WORD) (uppercase W) consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
space.

Give a look to the [word motions](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/motion.html#word-motions).

Comment: If I could vote for two answers I would, since this resolves the specific question I asked.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: or `dE` -- delete until the end of the sequence of non-blank characters (does not include the following blank)

Comment: @BlakeBlackwell  Who says you can not vote for two answers? i have done so on this question already. This is v useful info .

Answer (score 20):

one possible solution is to use the delete with a search.

so type in `d/<space>` and vim will delete until it hits a space.

Comment: This is more general than `dW` because you can also use it to delete from the cursor to any character, such as `2d/+`, in this case -- which would delete the String concatenations as well.

Comment: you can do 2dW and this performs just as well. in fact I consider it a better solution since it will also work with tabs and other whitespace.  It also removes the trailing whitespace you want to delete until.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to delete from **anywhere** inside the WORD, and in a single command, just use 
`daW`

(you can of course use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> if you want to limit to a word)

I use it quite a lot because it spare a move to the begining of the word (in your case)

Comment: daw and daW behave the same for me - both delete the whole word no matter which letter my cursor is on.  Not sure why.

Comment: daw will not delete the white spaces after the word, whereas daW will

Answer (score 12):

- delete for the current position to a specific character example "

  ```
  dt"
  ```
- delete the word from the position cursor is on till the end of the word

  ```
  dw
  ```
- delete the entire word the cursor is on irrespective of the position the cursor is on the word, this also puts you in insert mode to enable you to insert immediately.

  ```
  diw
  ```

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> is the answer to your question, but <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> looks like it will solve your problem better.

Comment: It doesnt do anything for me.