# English mnemonics to Vim's shortcuts

Tags: vim

I realize that Vim's main author is Dutch, so I'll settle for those as well. I'm interested, do Vim's "control keys" have equivalents in the english language? You know, Ctrl-O for Open, Ctrl-N for New and so on.

Some of Vim's "control keys" could be assigned some meanings

```
(a) append / (i) insert
(w) word / b (back one word)
```

These are just those that I thought off the top of my head.

Do they all have some meaning (:e ?)

*I find it much easier to remember them if I know they mean something; they're not just randomly used keys.*

Comment: Not all keys can have an English equivalent. It'd be quite a coincidence if all actions started with a different letter. If you're having trouble remembering the combinations you can make up your own mnemonics (x deletes a character, x looks a bit like scissors etc).

Comment: @Juhana - Well, at least to try to give the others some sort of meaning. How would scissors remind me of deletion?

Comment: As a native Dutch speaker, I can attest that at no instance does it appear that the Dutch language has served as inspiration for command keys/combinations.

Comment: ...because scissors are used to cut things off?

Comment: @Rook: do you _insert_ scissors, usually? Also, feel free to just utter `Axe` while pressing `x`...

Comment: I can understand that this is being votes off topic (although Vim related questions have always been directed here), but not a real question(!?) How is it now a real question?

Comment: @Juhana - Scissors are used to cut things apart! Whether one part will eventually come off is optional.

Comment: Ctrl-X has been 'Cut' selection in Wordstar, Windows, and presumably many others. `Ex` in latin means 'out', `Ex` often indicates '_former_', X sounds like `Axe` (I do like to _axe_ a feature when the deadline looms) etc. (@Uku: now whether `e` stands for edit, seems up for debate? ^-;)

Comment: @sehe - Good grief, you're right. I use those shortcuts so often it's amazing how I couldn't think of that.

Comment: @sehe: see "help edit": :e[dit] [++opt] [+cmd]  Edit the current file.

Comment: @Uku: humor lost on SO users. Let's have a snow fight.

Comment: The Command Z, X, C, V originate with Apple. The reason is that they are next to each other on the keyboard. And yes, X looks like scissors, and V like wedging something in. However x in vi is more likely to come from x-ing stuff out on a typewriter, I seem to recall from early vi documentation.

Comment: why does `dd` delete a line? what is the mnenomic there, and is the same pattern used anywhere else? Like does `cc` change a line?

Comment: Most of normal mode keys are obvious, but what about mnemonics for Ctrl+key shortcuts?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In normal mode:

- `a`: append
- `b`: beginning (of current or previous word)
- `c`: change
- `d`: delete
- `e`: end (of current word)
- `f`: find (next given character on current line)
- `g`: go (used as "leader" for many commands)
- `h`: left (only makes sense on the keyboard used by vi's author, same for `jkl`)
- `i`: insert
- `j`: down
- `k`: up
- `l`: right
- `m`: mark
- `n`: next (occurrence of last search)
- `o`: open (new line below current line)
- `p`: put (paste)
- `q`: quote? (record a macro in given register)
- `r`: replace
- `s`: substitute
- `t`: toward (next given character on current line)
- `u`: undo
- `v`: (enter) visual mode
- `w`: (next) word
- `x`: x-out (delete a single character)
- `y`: yank
- `z`: fold (it's visual, it looks like a folded sheet of paper)

Comment: Any body have any good mnemonics for $ (to go to end of line) and ^ (to go to beginning of line)? These symbols are also used in regular expressions, but is there an English mnemonic for them?

Comment: @NikoBellic Off the top of my head, how about:

$: "The buck stops here", implies the end
^: "Carrot (caret) and stick", the carrot is first

Comment: @NikoBellic: I came here just after learning using of $ in a tutorial :)

Comment: @NikoBellic you take out a mortgage to buy a house (^ - looks like a roof) and then you make payments ($).

Comment: The boss dangles a carrot `^` at the *start* of each workday, but you always have to wait until the very *end* to get paid `$`

Answer (score 9):

Some do. Check out this cheatsheet, it has a lot of mnemonics:

http://michael.peopleofhonoronly.com/vim/

Some of the more obvious ones:

- `y` = yank
- `c` = change
- `O` = over
- `f` = find
- `r` = replace
- `u` = undo
- `t` = unTil character

Comment: I always though of `t` as "to". As in "yank _to_ a"

Comment: @Alex: I thought of it as _`till_

Comment: If you put them all together, it *almost* spells factOry!

Answer (score 3):

My mnemonic for `^` (go to beginning of line): `^` looks like a roof, roof symbolizes home. `Home` key moves your cursor to the start of line/document.

Look at [ADM-3A keyboard layout](http://dudarev.com/i/adm-3a-keyboard-500-277.jpg): the `Home` key is used to print `^` and `~` symbols.