# IdeaVim Deleting from current position until semicolon

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

For regular VIM it is possible to delete characters through a certain character, as evident in this post about [deleting from current position until a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607904/vim-deleting-from-current-position-until-a-space). This seems to also work in IdeaVIM for the most part. For instance, pressing "dfx" will delete through the character "x". However, if you specify the character as ";" IdeaVim will not behave as expected. Instead of deleting through the semicolon, it does nothing. Is there a way that I can have ";" accepted as a valid character for this IdeaVIM command?

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64833/vi-shortcut-to-delete-until-the-next-x-character) post seems to suggest that "dfX" will delete forward through character 'X'. I'm looking for the same behavior applied to the semicolon character, but IdeaVim seems to not accept ";" as a valid character

Comment: I don't use IdeaVim, so this might be dumb; but, does using a backslash work?  I.e., `df\;`

Comment: Seems to be a bug in IdeaVIM plugin, as `df;` works in vim. Report it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM

Comment: IdeaVim is not Vim so there is no reason whatsoever to expect anything to work in it like it does in Vim. Use their issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dt;` in this case.

1. Delete
2. To
3. ;

`dt;`

To go to previous `;` you can do `dT;` as capital `T` ensures backwards navigation.